NamedParameterJdbcTemplate does not work properly when working with placeholders
I have something very tricky for you.
Ill explain:
I have a Java Spring Boot backend and this method in my persistence layer:
  public Map<TournamentHorse, Horse> getGenerateFirstRound(long id) throws NotFoundException {
    LOG.trace("getGenerateFirstRound({})", id);

    MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameterSource.addValue("idTour", id + "");
    Map<TournamentHorse, Horse> returnMap = new HashMap<>();

    String newReq = SQL_GET_GENERATE_FIRST_ROUND.replaceAll(":idTour", id + "");

    jdbcNamed.query(SQL_GET_GENERATE_FIRST_ROUND, parameterSource, result -> {
      TournamentHorse tournamentHorse = new TournamentHorse()
              .setTournamentId(result.getLong("tournament_id"))
              .setHorseId(result.getLong("horse_id"))
              .setEntryNumber(result.getObject("entryNumber") == null ? null : result.getLong("entryNumber"))
              .setRoundReached(1L);

      Horse horse = new Horse()
              .setId(result.getLong("id"))
              .setName(result.getString("name"))
              .setSex(Sex.valueOf(result.getString("sex")))
              .setDateOfBirth(result.getDate("date_of_birth").toLocalDate())
              .setHeight(result.getFloat("height"))
              .setWeight(result.getFloat("weight"))
              .setBreedId(result.getLong("breed_id"));

      returnMap.put(tournamentHorse, horse);
    });

    if (returnMap.isEmpty()) {
      throw new NotFoundException("Tournament participants not found");
    }
    if (returnMap.size() != 8) {
      LOG.error("Tournament participants wrong quantity of horses: size=" + returnMap.size());
      throw new FatalException("Tournament participants wrong quantity of horses: size=" + returnMap.size());
    }

    return returnMap;
  }

My problem is the following:
When I run the code, the jbdcNamed query returns an empty set and thus the NotFoundException gets throwen.
You might think this is a problem with my database (H2) or my sql statement.
That was also my first instinct. But no, I actually do not think that thats the case.
Because after some testing, when I replace the SQL_GET_GENERATE_FIRST_ROUND with newReq in the line jdbcNamed.query(SQL_GET_GENERATE_FIRST_ROUND, parameterSource, result -> { the code works and it returns the expected values!
Here is the code for the SQL_GET_GENERATE_FIRST_ROUND variable:
  private static final String SQL_GET_GENERATE_FIRST_ROUND =
          // get all participants points
          "WITH PARTICIPANTS_WITH_POINTS as ("
          + "With Points as (SELECT th.horse_id, h.name, h.date_of_birth, sum(CASE WHEN th.roundReached = 4 THEN 5 "
          + "WHEN th.roundReached = 3 THEN 3 "
          + "WHEN th.roundReached = 2 THEN 1 "
          + "ELSE 0 END) points "
          + "FROM " + TABLE_NAME_PARTICIPANT + " th "
          + "join " + TABLE_NAME_HORSE + " h on th.horse_id = h.id "
          + "join " + TABLE_NAME + " t on t.id = th.TOURNAMENT_ID and t.START_DATE between "
          + "(SELECT DATEADD('MONTH', -12, START_DATE) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id=:idTour) "
          + "AND "
          + "(SELECT START_DATE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id=:idTour) "
          + "group by th.horse_id) "
          + "SELECT th.TOURNAMENT_ID, th.HORSE_ID, th.ENTRYNUMBER, th.ROUNDREACHED, NAME, Points "
          + "FROM " + TABLE_NAME_PARTICIPANT + " th "
          + "join Points p on th.HORSE_ID = p.horse_id and (th.TOURNAMENT_ID=:idTour) "
          + "order by p.points desc, p.NAME asc), "
          // rank the 8 horses
          + "RankedEntries as (SELECT TOURNAMENT_ID, horse_id, name, points, "
          + "row_number() over (order by points desc, name asc) as rank, "
          + "COUNT(*) over () as total_count from PARTICIPANTS_WITH_POINTS), "
          // create the entity number based on RankedEnties
          + "CrossPaired AS ("
          + "SELECT TOURNAMENT_ID, HORSE_ID, name, rank, total_count, "
          + "case when rank <= (total_count / 2) THEN (rank * 2) - 1 "
          + "else (total_count + 1 - rank) * 2 "
          + "end as entryNumber "
          + "from RankedEntries) "
          + "select cp.TOURNAMENT_ID, cp.HORSE_ID, entryNumber, h.* from CrossPaired cp join "
          + TABLE_NAME_HORSE + " h on h.id = cp.HORSE_ID order by entryNumber asc;";

Ill give some extra infos / things I already tried:

Tried changing the placeholder to something else. (nothing changed)
Tried debuging the code and getting the LOGs from the jdbc. (below)
Tried restarting everything
Tried using JdbcTemplate instead of NamedParameterJdbcTemplate (changed nothing, same behaviour)

Logs from jdbc
Executing prepared SQL statement [WITH PARTICIPANTS_WITH_POINTS as (With Points as (SELECT th.horse_id, h.name, h.date_of_birth, sum(CASE WHEN roundReached = 4 THEN 5   WHEN roundReached = 3 THEN 3   WHEN roundReached = 2 THEN 1                                                             ELSE 0 END) points FROM TOURNAMENT_HORSE th  join horse h on th.horse_id = h.id join TOURNAMENT t on t.id = th.TOURNAMENT_ID and t.START_DATE between (SELECT DATEADD('MONTH', -12, START_DATE) FROM TOURNAMENT WHERE id = ?)  AND   (SELECT START_DATE FROM TOURNAMENT WHERE id = ?)  group by th.horse_id) SELECT TOURNAMENT_ID, th.HORSE_ID, ENTRYNUMBER, ROUNDREACHED, NAME, Points from TOURNAMENT_HORSE th join Points p on th.HORSE_ID = p.horse_id and th.TOURNAMENT_ID = ? order by p.points desc, p.NAME asc),RankedEntries as (SELECT TOURNAMENT_ID, horse_id, name, points,  row_number() over (order by points desc, name asc) as rank,  COUNT(*) over () as total_count from PARTICIPANTS_WITH_POINTS),CrossPaired AS (    SELECT TOURNAMENT_ID, HORSE_ID, name, rank, total_count,  case when rank <= (total_count / 2) THEN (rank * 2) - 1  else (total_count + 1 - rank) * 2 end as entryNumber from RankedEntries ) select cp.TOURNAMENT_ID, cp.HORSE_ID, entryNumber, h.* from CrossPaired cp join HORSE h on h.id = cp.HORSE_ID order by entryNumber asc]

The strange thing when I connect to the database via console and replace the ? from the logs with the correct value it works and returns the expected result!

I find it weird that query returns an empty map rather than an error.

Has anyone had such a problem, knows a possible workaround without using .replaceAll or knows things I can try?

first show the complete text of SQL_GET_GENERATE_FIRST_ROUND  , also show the complete error trace back

I can't say 100% but I think the problem here is that you are converting id to a string, when it is a number type in your database. This mismatch could cause the prepared statement to fail if there is no typecast. I would try this instead:
parameterSource.addValue("idTour", Long.valueOf(id));

